# Iterating Through multiple dropdowns in jquery

Tags: jquery

Hi I have for loop which iterates and set the multiple dropdowns i want to iterate each of the dropdown and to print selected value in that page
here is my code

```
<select  name="occupation" id="myselect">
                    <option>Choose One</option>
                     <%if (list != null
                                        && list.size() > 0) {
                        for (Map.Entry<String,String> entry : list.entrySet()) {                            
                                        if(!entry.getValue().equals(user1.getName())){%>
                      <option id="<%=user.getid()%>" value="<%=entry.getKey()%>"><%=entry.getValue()%></option>

                      <%}}}%> 
                    </select>
```

jQuery:

```
$('#myselect').change(function(){
        var id=$('#myselect option:selected').attr('id');
        var text=$('#myselect option:selected').text();
        alert(id);
        alert(text);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `each()`

```
 $('#myselect').change(function(){
   $('#myselect option:selected').each(function(){
        alert(this.value);
        alert($(this).attr('id'));
        alert($(this).text());
   });
  });
```

**after comment..**

If you have multiple dropdown .. then you have to change your ids.. **since id should always be unique**... change it to class and use class selector

```
  $('.myselect').change(function(){
   $(this).find('option:selected').each(function(){
        alert(this.value);
        alert($(this).attr('id'));
        alert($(this).text());
   });
  });
```

Comment: I want the value to be triggered on changing of the particular dropdown

Comment: updated my answer...check it out

Comment: bipen thanks for that ,the code is working for the first dropdown only

Comment: first dropdown!!!! you mean to say you have multiple dropdown with same id... if it is so then that is invalid... name all you dropdown with same class and call calss selector.... `$('.myselect')` instead of `$('#myselect')`

Comment: If i want only particular selected value (if it is selected otherwise not) what i have to do

Comment: particular selected value!!! then i think there is no use of multiple select.. anyways use if condition to check for particular value, if the value that or not... `if(this.value == yourvalue){..}`.. inside the each loop :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to select $("select option:selected") selector :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("select option:selected").each(function(i, obj){
    alert($(this).html());
   });
});
```